# What does it mean when a sentence ends with しなくもない?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

A friend posted this in a comment on Facebook:

> これは深{ふか}い意味{いみ}があるような気{き}がしなくもない

I think I get the general meaning, which is "This seems to have a deep meaning." But I'm fuzzy on the implications of `しなくもない`.

Is it a contraction of `かも知{し}れない`? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a double negation. It is a way of saying "する" with less certainty.

Comment: How does it compare with sentence patterns like でしょう and かもしれない in terms of expressing certainty?