# Repetition and meaning of なくも

Tags: grammar, meaning

I am currently reading 天気の子 by 新海誠。There is a passage which I can't figure out which uses the phrase なくも over and over. Other posts mention なく or も separately, but not together (that I've found). I understand that "～もない （～もなく） can mean 'not even～' or 'without (even) ～' but I was wondering what なくも means instead. Also, why are there no commas between the repetitions. Sorry if this has been asked/answered elsewhere. Here is the sentence:

ーような気が、しなくも、なくもなくも、なくもなくもなくもない。

Comment: You need to first understand single しなくもない. These are related: [Question about しなくもない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50474/43676), [What does it mean when a sentence ends with しなくもない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5446/43676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a creative choice to show an idea in the character's mind flopping over and over, trying to figure it out.
Kind of like - "...or that's what it seems...or not? Or not not? Or not not not?"

Comment: Thank you, a bit like they are saying "I think you should not not do it, but maybe you should? Or shouldn't?"

Comment: @palmon - しなくもない is the standard form. しなくもなくもない is sometimes said jokingly. This is an extreme case of that.